# Why isn't my DoubleAnimation working?

Tags: c#, easing, wpf-animation, hamburger-menu, doubleanimation

I'm trying to make a custom hamburger menu for my app.  I have the layout all setup, but, for some reason, my `DoubleAnimation` isn't working as I expect.  I'm trying to accomplish something similar to Cortana's hamburger menu on Windows 10.  I'm creating my `Storyboard` and `DoubleAnimation` in my code (I still have the same problem even if my animation is created in XAML).  Here's what I have:

```
menuButton.Click += (s, e) => {
    if (menuIsOpen) {
        Animate(
            menuPanel,
            "Width",
            ActualWidth, //Page.ActualWidth
            50,
            0.1,
            new Duration(new TimeSpan(TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond)));
    }
    else {
        Animate(
            menuPanel,
            "Width",
            50,
            ActualWidth, //Page.ActualWidth
            0.1,
            new Duration(new TimeSpan(TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond)));
    }
    menuIsOpen = !menuIsOpen;
};
```

This is the signature for `Animate()`:

```
private void Animate(DependencyObject item, string property, double from, double to, double? by, Duration duration) {
    var storyboard = new Storyboard();
    var animation = new DoubleAnimation();
    animation.From = from;
    animation.To = to;
    animation.Duration = duration;
    animation.EasingFunction = new SineEase() { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseInOut };
    animation.By = by;
    Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, item);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, property);
    storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
    storyboard.Begin();
}
```

I used a little `Debug.WriteLine()` to see if the `Storyboard` is actually running, which it is.  The `menuPanel`'s width does not change at all.  I've used a similar approach with some of my other projects and it works fine there.

> EDIT:
>   I thought I'd add a little bit more detail.
>   My app is targeting Windows 10
>   and I'm able to change the width of `menuPanel` freely if I don't use `Storyboard`s and `DoubleAnimation`s.

Comment: you can try `menuPanel.BeginAnimation(menuPanel.WidthProperty, animation);` see if it works for you

Comment: @MohitShrivastava I don't have the method `BeginAnimation`.  MSDN says it is a part of `PresentationCore.dll`, which I located and added to my solution, but still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this answer on a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13339062/3908547), and my animation works just fine now.

> I figured it out myself. All I had to do was to Enable Dependent Animation (EnableDependentAnimation) on the DoubleAnimation as this animation affects the layout. And then it worked perfectly.