# Why doesn't binding to a property work when used in local window resources?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a storyboard with an animation in MainWindow.xaml Window.Resources section:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="ShowSearchGrid">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="SearchGrid">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="{Binding ExpandedGridHeight}"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
```

The property ExpandedGridHeight is defined in a custom class like so:

```
class ExpandedGridHeightClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //The next bit handles the INotifyPropertyChanged implementation

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void Notify(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public Double ExpandedGridHeight
    {
        get { return _expandedGridHeight; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _expandedGridHeight)
            {
                _expandedGridHeight = value;
                Notify("ExpandedGridHeight");
            }
        }
    }

    private Double _expandedGridHeight = 100;
}
```

The data context for the window is set in MainWindow():

```
ExpandedGridHeightClass ExpandedHeight;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ExpandedHeight = new ExpandedGridHeightClass();
    this.DataContext = ExpandedHeight;
}
```

The actual value for ExpandedHeight's ExpandedGridHeight property is set elsewhere, and changes depending on the size of the window.

The storyboard is started from the following function:

```
void showSearchGrid()
{
    Storyboard ShowSearchGrid = this.FindResource("ShowSearchGrid") as Storyboard;
    ShowSearchGrid.Begin();
}
```

When I tried to bind the property to various other places like to the title of the window, it worked perfectly, and updated exactly as intended. However, when it is binded like in the code examples to a property in the local resources, it doesn't work: the animation does start as usual, but instead of animating to ExpandedGridHeight, the SearchGrid is animated to a height value of 0. I'm suspecting it is because the animation is defined in the resources, but don't know a fix to this problem. Any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: @Steve No luck with that, unfortunately.

Comment: Does this work for the binding? `{Binding DataContext.ExpandedGridHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}`? (this assumes that `ExpandedGridHeight` is a member of the window's viewmodel -- but I think that's a safe assumption from what you say)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storyboard DoubleAnimation Does not work with StackPanel Height Property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13334470/storyboard-doubleanimation-does-not-work-with-stackpanel-height-property)

Comment: Binding does not work property in resources. My understanding is that it has no visual tree nor datacontext when it is inside a resource dictionary.

Comment: @EdPlunkett thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't work. My knowledge of viewmodels is quite limited, so I can't exactly say whether your assumption is correct or not.

Comment: @Jai yes, that seems to be the case, and further googling confirms this. Would there be any way around this limitation? I'm starting to feel like I should look for alternative ways to implement the animations, since binding within resource dictionaries is so problematic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just thought I might as well put this as an answer. This method is definitely "hackish", so it may not be to your liking.

ExpandedGridHeightClass:

```
class ExpandedGridHeightClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private static ExpandedGridHeightClass _instance;
    public static ExpandedGridHeightClass Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
                _instance = new ExpandedGridHeightClass();
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Whatever your class already has
     */
}
```

XAML:

```
<EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5"
    Value="{Binding ExpandedGridHeight, Source={x:Static MyNamespace:ExpandedGridHeightClass.Instance}}"/>
```